# Set variable for a controller - Laravel 4

Tags: php, controller, laravel, global-variables, laravel-4

So here is the thing. I need someway to set a global variable for the whole controller.

I need it because all of the actions in the controller is going to need to receive the data via the GET method.

I thought that maybe placing it in the __construct will make it work like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->team_id = Input::get('team_id');
}
```

But it says team_id is not found....

Thanks for your help,
Ara

Answer (score 3):

Do you set a global variable name $team_id in your controller class before set it into `__construct` ?
Because it will fail if you want to set an unknown variable.

Comment: I tried placing a global variable but I get: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Global for your class, define a variable like private $team_id; just before your __construct function

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending the 'team_id' value as part of the request to your controller?
You can check if it is being sent by using Input::has()

```
$this->team_id = Input::has('team_id') ? Input::get('team_id') : 1 /* Default value */ ;
```

Edit:

Or, if you can't use a default id then you can replace the '1' in the example with a redirect containing a message such as : '{"response":"No team id supplied!"}'

Comment: Are you running this in a constructor?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, my constructor doesn't seem to get triggered so my variable is never set...